# Ruby on Rails: Route a deprecated URL to application's root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How would I write the Rails route in config/routes.rb when I need to point a deprecated URL that still exists on someone else's website I can't control (`'/something/article.jsp?id=1787'`) to the root of my application?

How would the below (wrong) attempt need to be corrected?

```
get '/something/article.jsp?id=1787' => 'root#index'
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect a page on a another domain to your app's root url? That's never going to work. DNS for that domain is going to direct to that server, not your app's. Or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: You're misundertanding it. Someone published the URL ```http://www.example.com/something/article.jsp?id=1787``` on their website but this path doesn't exist anymore at my website www.example.com. Since I don't control "someone's" website, I can't correct that URL and therfor want to simply have it point to the root of my website at www.example.com.

Comment: Have what exactly point to your website? You don't control that domain DNS, or do you?

Comment: Have the URL ```http://www.example.com/something/article.jsp?id=1787``` point to (or: "route to") the root of my app, in ```config/routes.rb``` (not at the DNS level, ```example.com``` being my website.)

Comment: It is your domain. Okay. Then the the 301 redirect makes perfect sense. Your question stating "someone else's website I can't control" made it seem you were attempting to redirect a different domain to your domain via your routes.db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `constraint`:

```
get '/something/article', to: redirect('/'),
      :constraints => lambda { |request| request.params[:id] == '1787' }
```

This creates a 301 "Moved Permanently" redirect.

If you don't want to do a redirect, but instead want that URL to simply trigger the `root#index` action, you can substitute the `to: redirect('/')` line for `to: 'root#index'`. However, this approach will keep the old URL in the address bar.

- More info on redirects [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection).
- More info on constraints [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried ```get '/something/article.jsp?id=1787', to: redirect('/')``` but it throws a 404 (you can try it in one of your apps).

Comment: I have tested a few approaches in a sample app. I've updated the answer with code that worked for the sample app. Hope it works for you too!